# Does my code solve the question? I am a beginner in python

Tags: python

Write a program that generates 100 random numbers and keeps a count of how many of those random numbers are even, and how many of them are odd.

```
import random 

def main():
    print("There",even(),"even numbers\n")
    print("There",odd(),"even numbers")        

def even():
     even_count=0
     for i in range(0,100):
        x= random.randint(1,100)# genreates random numbers 
        if (x % 2) == 0:#finds odd numbers
            even_count += 1 #keeps count of even  numbers
     return even_count 

def odd():
    odd_count=0
    for i in range(0,100):
        x= random.randint(1,100)# genreates random numbers 
        if (x % 2) != 0: #finds odd numbers
            odd_count+=1 #keeps count of odd numbers
    return odd_count
```

Comment: Hi! Please be specific about the problem you're facing, and paste any error messages you see

Comment: Your solution will call even() in which 100 numbers will be generated and odd() in which also 100 numbers will be generated. Do u want to generate random numbers separately or just once?

Comment: You would probably expect the even number and odd number to add up 100. This wont be the case if you count the odds and evens from two different lists of numbers. So generate the numbers first. Then count the odds and you can work out the evens by subtraction.

Comment: Just call `even()` and then subtract the result from 100 to find out the number of odd numbers. You don't need the `odd()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're supposed to count evens and odds in the same bag of numbers, then no as you're not counting the same collection for each function.

i.e. you're generating 100 numbers and counting how many are even, then generating 100 more new numbers and counting how many are odd.

Do you even need separate functions? Can a number be anything other than even or odd?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and No. You technically generate 200 random numbers.

Since you call `even()` and it generates 100, then `odd()` and it does the same, 100 + 100 = 200.

You can do it this way:

```
from random import randint

even = sum(randint(0, 100) % 2 == 0 for _ in range(0, 100))
odd = 100 - even

print('{} Even, {} Odd'.format(even, odd)
```

An alternative, and slightly faster approach, is a lazy tracker. It basically stores the sequentially generated number (i.e. `range()`) and not the randomly generated one. Since you dont care what numbers are generated, we just use the sequentially generated count as the number of successful conditions in the comprehension:

```
even = len([x for x in range(0, 100) if randint(0, 100) % 2 == 0])
odd = 100 - even
```

This approach is a few seconds faster because unlike `sum()` we don't have to go back and count the number of `True` occurrences (which `sum()` treats as `1`). Thus we store whatever number in the range we were at, and let the native list attribute of `list.length` get updated along the way. The number of successful stores is the number of even values generated.

Comment: no need to create a list just to compute its len. do `even = sum(randint(0, 100) % 2 == 0 for _ in range(0, 100))`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Quite right. In fact, my original post always made `even` 100 since it contained 100 booleans. Doing it with lists would require an nested expression.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Actually, see my update. Slightly faster than `sum()` on occassion since `len()` is constant time and we don't care about what the randomly generated number is.

Comment: did you bench that? because creating a list is costly. `len` is not an issue but you're creating a list first. I'm pretty sure that if you bench that `sum` wins

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yea I benched it, `sum` loses every time by ~10-15s; using `timeit.timeit()`. I'd have to run a lot more tests, but it would appear that because `sum` has to go back over, the appending operation of building a list is slightly more optimized than when `sum` is iterating. Granted this isn't always the case, as sometimes `sum` is faster. Depends on how many "randomy" evens are generated. Either way, I still think `sum` is better since its a generator expression.

Comment: probably because of `sum` having to call the comprehension, when list comprehensions are super fast. With bigger values than `100` (like 1000000) I'm sure the tendency inverts.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm sure you're correct. The several tests I have run yielding varying results. Depends on the sample size and "randomness" of them.

Comment: which can be explained by: with 100, list comprehension memory allocation doesn't have to perform too many costly realloc+memory copy. With bigger values, there are a lot of memory copies. Which doesn't happen in `sum` version. I'd like to see that in your answer, you wouldn't want to give the impression that creating a list is faster than counting for the general case.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Oh maths.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need those separate methods for `even` and `odd` numbers, instead just keep a `counter` for both:

```
import random

even_count = 0
odd_count = 0

for i in range(0,100):
    x = random.randint(1,100)# genreates random numbers
    if (x % 2) != 0:  # finds odd numbers
        odd_count += 1
    else:
        even_count += 1
print("There are {} even and {} odd numbers.".format(even_count, odd_count))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
There are 51 even and 49 odd numbers.
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your approach. You only need one function:

```
import random 

def main():
    even,odd = generator()
    print("There are ",even," even numbers\n")
    print("There are ",odd," odd numbers")        

def generator():
    even_count = 0
    odd_count = 0
    for i in range(0,100):
        x= random.randint(1,100)# genreates random numbers 
        if (x % 2) == 0: #finds odd numbers
           even_count += 1 #keeps count of even  numbers
        else:
           odd_count += 1 #keeps count of odd numbers
    return even_count,odd_count

main()
```

*Hope this answers your question!!*

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
even=0
odd=0
for i in range (100):
    r=random.randint(0,100)
    if r%2==0:
        even+=1
    else :
        odd+=1
print("even : "+str(even)+" and odd : "+ str(odd))
```

Answer (score 0):

In one line your problem can be expressed as `count = len(filter(predicate, values))`
Implementing this:

```
from random import randint

count = len(filter(lambda _: randint(1,100)%2 == 0, range(100)))
print '{0} even, {1} odd.'.format(count, 100-count)
```

Although in practice you should probably break the program down into intermediate steps that provide intermediate values that will be useful in your algorithm.

```
def is_even(x):
    return x % 2 == 0

def is_odd(x):
    return x % 2 == 1

values = [randint(1,100) for _ in range(100)]

evens = filter(is_even, values)
odds = filter(is_odd, values)

print '{0} even, {1} odd.'.format(len(evens), len(odds))
```

Outputs:

```
47 even, 53 odd.
53 even, 47 odd.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 200 numbers. 
you can do this in a one function

```
import random 

def main():
    odd , even = odd_or_even()
    print("There",even,"even numbers\n")
    print("There",odd,"even numbers")

def odd_or_even():
     even_count=0
     odd_count=0
     for i in range(0,100):
        x= random.randint(1,100)# genreates random numbers 
        if (x % 2) == 0:#finds odd numbers
            even_count += 1 #keeps count of even  numbers
        else:
            odd_count+=1 #keeps count of odd numbers

     return odd_count, even_count
```

Answer (score 0):

I smooshed your code into a smaller script because at first there was quite a bit of unnecessary code. Also your code definitely answers the question.
import random
from random import randint

```
def main():
     even_count=0
     odd_count = 0
     for i in range(0,100):
        x = randint(1,100)# genreates random numbers 
        if (x % 2) == 0:#finds odd numbers
            even_count += 1 #keeps count of even  numbers
        else:
            odd_count += 1
     print(even_count)
     print(odd_count)
main()
```

Answer (score -1):

How I would do it, remove as much fuss as you can from your code, if you're repeating code you can make it simpler.

```
import random

def main():
    random_numbers = [random.randrange(1, 101) for i in range(100)]
    print(f'There are {len([x for x in random_numbers if x % 2 >= 1])} even numbers.\n'
          f'There are {len([x for x in random_numbers if x % 2 == 0])} odd numbers.')

main()

# There are 45 even numbers.
# There are 55 odd numbers.
```

Comment: Your code calls `odd_or_even()` twice, that is not needed. **Update**: Even with your change, you iterate the container twice, you only need to do it once.

Comment: @pstatix yeah I realised :P fixed it, now its just one function

Comment: The difference between yours and mine is there actually exists a list of odd and even numbers if one were needing to access them, you're just subtracting from 100 and getting the possible remainder. So its dependent on what you want to do.

Comment: OP asked to generate a single set of 100 numbers. Therefore if you compute that 23 of those 100 were even, the remaining 77 are odd. I suggest you reread the post and update your solution accordingly.